# How to rebuild bootstrap-grid.css from scss files

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to recompile bootstrap-grid.css from its SASS files which are in .scss format.
These .scss files are the ones provided [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) under "Source files".

Current bootstrap version is v4.13

Right now, I am performing the following;

```
sass bootstrap-grid.scss bootstrap-grid.css
```

However, when I compare the bootstrap-grid.css that I have manually created with the bootstrap-grid.css that is readily downloadable, the results are different.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how the 2 files are different? Is your generated version missing classes that the orginal bootstrap-grid.css contains?

Comment: The generated version is missing alot of "ms-*" properties , that are present in the readily downloadable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bootstrap generated version uses Autoprefixer](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#source-files) which will add the vendor prefixes like `-ms-` in the CSS.